# Predefining a complex replacement for substitution

Tags: regex, perl, variables, substitution, evaluation

I am trying to use variables in `s///`. This example code works as expected:

```
my $regex1 = "e";
my $regex2 = "2";

my @array = ("one two three", "green blue red");

$_ =~ s/$regex1/$regex2/gee foreach (@array);

print $_ foreach (@array);
```

However, if I try to do a more complex regex, such as:

```
my $regex1 = "^(\w)";
my $regex2 = "\u$1";
```

Then the substitution doesn't work at all. I get the feeling Perl is literally looking for "caret parenthesis backslash" and so on, and not interpreting it as a regex.

Comment: That's a very convoluted and (as you've discovered) error-prone way to implement [`ucfirst`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html).

Comment: This is merely a simplified example for a more complex script involving variable complex regexes generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent interpolation of meta-characters:

```
my $regex1 = '^(\w)';
my $regex2 = '"\u$1"';
```

(Updated according to @ThisSuitIsBlackNot's comment)

The reason is that Perl interpolates double-quoted strings, so your variables `$regex1` and `$regex2` do not contain what you need:

```
my $regex1 = "^(\w)";
my $regex2 = "\u$1";
print "$regex1\n"; # ^(w)
print "$regex2\n"; # empty line
```

So, the substitution operator works as `s/^(w)//gee` and, of course, fails to find anything.

Comment: `my $regex2 = '\u$1';` isn't enough, you need `my $regex2 = q{"\u$1"};`

Comment: Say the $regex variables are being split from a string input by the user, so they type "first part/second part" and it splits on "/" to produce $regex1 and $regex2 for the s/// line. How can I prevent interpolation in this instance as well? Thanks!

Comment: Enclosing into quotes works, at least, with the example you gave: `my ($regex1, $regex2) = split '/', $line; $regex2 = '"' . $regex2 . '"';` By the way, do not forget to `chomp` the input line, otherwise newline will be considered a part of the regexp too.

Answer (score 0):

You *really* don't want to do this, because allowing people to pass Perl code into your program that will be given to `eval` isn't a nice thing to do. Apart from being horribly complex it will open you to malice without careful checking. If someone typed `aaa/"unlink *"` then the necessary `/ee` will delete your current folder

Let's clear something up first. In `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`, only `PATTERN` is a regex. `REPLACEMENT` is a simple string evaluated as if it were in double quotes

So lets write your program like this. I've put all of your strings in single quotes as you don't want to use escape sequences or variable interpolation. I've also chnaged your `/eeg` modifiers to just `/g`. It looks like you were spraying `/e` around in the hope that it might work, and that's no way to write software

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $regex       = 'e';
my $replacement = '2';

my @array = ('one two three', 'green blue red');

s/$regex/$replacement/g for @array;

print "$_\n" for @array;
```

#### output

```
on2 two thr22
gr22n blu2 r2d
```

Now you wanted to change this to

```perl
my $regex       = "^(\w)";
my $replacement = "\u$1";
```

and this is why I threw out your double quotes. Perl tries to compile `"^(\w)"` and sees `\w` as an escape sequence that it doesn't recognise, so you get

> ```
> Unrecognized escape \w passed through
> ```

and it assumes that you meant just `w`. Unless you want to escape the backslashes like `"^(\\w)"` you need single quotes to represent the string `^(\w)`

A similar thing applies to `$replacement`.
 = "\u$1";

The first thing you'll see is Perl trying to interpolate the current value of `$1` into the double-quoted string. It's currently undefined, so you get

> ```
> Use of uninitialized value $1 in ucfirst
> ```

But even so it obliges and uses the empty string for `$1` and then upper-cases it for you leaving ... the empty string

So now you have set

```perl
$regex       = '^(w)';
$replacement = '';
```

so it's unsurprising that nothing works

Let's do your program again, but this time using single quotes so that nothing gets messed with

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $regex       = '^(\w)';
my $replacement = '\u$1';

my @array = ('one two three', 'green blue red');

s/$regex/$replacement/g for @array;

print "$_\n" for @array;
```

Now `$regex` really is `^(\w)` and `$replacement` really is `\u$1`. What can go wrong?

It works fine. We get

```
\u$1ne two three
\u$1reen blue red
```

which is exactly what we asked for

But now your `/e` modifier comes in useful. A *single* `/e` evaluates the `REPLACEMENT` as an *expression*. That would be useful if we wanted to stick `$1 . 'xxx'` or similar in there, but since the expression is `$replacement` we get no advantage at all: the expression `$replacement` is the same as interpolating `$replacement`

Do we need another `/e`? That will call `eval` on the result of the first `/e`, so we're asking for `eval '\u$1'`, and that won't compile since `\u$1` isn't a viable Perl program, so `eval` returns `undef` and we get

> ```
> Use of uninitialized value in substitution iterator
> ```

The solution is to make `$replacement` into a compileable program. Putting double quotes around it, like `"\u$1"` turns it into a very short Perl program which returns the current value of `$1` with the first character upper-cased

We need to set `$replacement` to that string, including the double quotes and avoiding the processing of escaped characters and `$1` as before. If I write

```perl
my $replacement = '"\u$1"';
```

then I get exactly the string `"\u$1"` including the double-quotes

Now let's try

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $regex       = '^(\w)';
my $replacement = '"\u$1"';

my @array = ('one two three', 'green blue red');

s/$regex/$replacement/eeg for @array;

print "$_\n" for @array;
```

#### output

```
One two three
Green blue red
```

As I said, you ***really*** don't want to do this!